# repository @local_jdk which failed to fetch. no such package '@local_jdk//': java.io.IOException: Could not create symlink

Tags: scala, bazel, symlink

I'm trying to Hello World example scala file according to on my windows 10 desktop:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala
My `WORKSHOP` file is as recommended in the rules_scala repo.

My `BUILD` file is as follows:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_test", "scala_binary")
scala_binary(
    name = "helloworld",
    srcs = ["HelloWorld.scala"],
    main_class="HelloWorld",
)
```

I've set my environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to where my `javac.exe` file is located. But when I try to build it, I get the following:

EDIT: After enabling developer mode on windows, the first half of the error disappeared, but still get:

```
PS C:\Users\m80\Documents\GitHub\BotsForGames\HexAgony\src\hexagony> bazel build :helloworld
INFO: Repository local_jdk instantiated at:
  /DEFAULT.WORKSPACE.SUFFIX:40:22: in <toplevel>
Repository rule local_java_repository defined at:
  C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/local_java_repository.bzl:66:40: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_jdk':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/local_java_repository.bzl", line 46, column 35, in _local_java_repository_impl
                repository_ctx.symlink(file, file.basename)
Error in symlink: java.io.IOException: Could not create symlink from C:/Users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/remotejdk11_win/BUILD.bazel to C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/local_jdk/BUILD.bazel: C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/local_jdk/BUILD.bazel (File exists)
ERROR: Error fetching repository: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/local_java_repository.bzl", line 46, column 35, in _local_java_repository_impl
                repository_ctx.symlink(file, file.basename)
Error in symlink: java.io.IOException: Could not create symlink from C:/Users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/remotejdk11_win/BUILD.bazel to C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/local_jdk/BUILD.bazel: C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/local_jdk/BUILD.bazel (File exists)
ERROR: C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/BUILD:336:6: @bazel_tools//tools/jdk:jdk depends on @local_jdk//:jdk in repository @local_jdk which failed to fetch. no such package '@local_jdk//': java.io.IOException: Could not create symlink from C:/Users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/remotejdk11_win/BUILD.bazel to C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/local_jdk/BUILD.bazel: C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80/4fgq25dr/external/local_jdk/BUILD.bazel (File exists)
ERROR: Analysis of target '//hexagony/src/hexagony:helloworld' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.588s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (3 packages loaded, 39 targets configured)
```

What does this mean? How could I resolve it? I couldn't seem to find many similar problems wrt Scala + Bazel

Comment: I guess the problem is that no symlinks can be created on your machine. Maybe the root cause is the you did not enable "Developer mode" on Windows 10. See [here](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us15594140/)

Comment: @Vertexwahn Thank you! So, that seems to solve the `error loading package '': Label '//3rdparty:workspace.bzl' is invalid because '3rdparty' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '//:3rdparty/workspace.bzl'?`

Comment: Editied the post after applying your suggestion

Comment: Delete your bazel cache, i.e. delete the folder ` C:/users/m80/_bazel_m80` on your system and than let Bazel build again. I guess before you had dev mode on Bazel tried to create symlinks - on for some reason it created invalid ones. Now after activation it tries this agian and run into problems - just guessing...